# How can I find failed systemd services?

Tags: systemd

When I run `systemctl status` on a specific server, I get the following output:

```
● ⟨host-name⟩
    State: degraded
     Jobs: 0 queued
   Failed: 1 units
    Since: Fr 2017-06-09 00:34:27 UTC; 1 weeks 5 days ago
   CGroup: /
…
```

How can I find out which of the services is the one that failed?

I tried it with `systemctl is-failed '*'`, but that doesn't yield any meaningful output (it outputs 39 lines `active` one `failed` line and then some more (> 100) `active`lines…).

Comment: Does `systemctl list-units --state=failed` not provide what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `is-failed` is the wrong sub command… who would have guessed.

here is some perl hackery to get the right answer:

```
$ systemctl list-units | perl -lanE'print if $F[2] !~ /active/'
  UNIT    LOAD   ACTIVE SUB       DESCRIPTION
● vboxautostart-service.service                                                             loaded failed failed    vboxautostart-service.service

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

207 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```

And `systemctl` is also that nice to clutter stderr with informational output in a way that we only get the output we want.

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
sudo systemctl list-units --failed
```

or

```
sudo systemctl list-units --state=failed
```

Comment: or just systemct --failed